# Does the function run when assigned to local variable

Tags: php

Below is the example I put together to understand my confusion. Now my question is, when I make the function into a local variable, does it start to run instantly or does it wait for the local variable to be called.

```
//Here is the function
function myFunction(){
    return 'Hello Stackoverflow';
}

//Does the functio run at this point
$stackoverflow = myFunction();

//Or does the function run here?
echo $stackoverflow;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You aren't making "the function into a local variable."

In your example the function runs, the string return value is assigned to $stackoverflow, then you echo the string.

I think you are trying to do this.

```
//Here is the function
function myFunction(){
    return 'Hello Stackoverflow';
}

//Doesn't run yet
$stackoverflow = 'myFunction';

//This runs now
echo $stackoverflow();
```

Comment: Now that's awesome. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, that is probably what the OP really meant,

Answer (score 4):

You are not actually assigning a function to the variable, but the return value of the function.

And yes, the function is executed when you call it, i.e. when you assign it to the variable.

After that of course you have a variable with a value and you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: To clarify, the function is actually run when it is called (with the `()` syntax), regardless of whether it is assigned to a variable or not. In this case, that does in fact happen in the same statement as the variable assignment.

Comment: @CarlGroner you're totally right but I was referring to the OP code.

Answer (score 2):

It will run at the time of assignment:

```
$stackoverflow = myFunction();
```

You could assign the function to the variable if you want it called when referencing the variable and not when it's assigned:

```
$foo = function () {
    return 'Hello Stackoverflow';
};

echo $foo();
```

Comment: Nope, I don't think you can do that, at least until PHP 5.6.

Comment: Perfectly valid before 5.6, anonymous functions (closures) were introduced in 5.3.0

Comment: @MarkBaker You are right and I stand corrected. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

The function run when it is assigned to a value, i.e, at `$stackoverflow = myFunction();`